# Sandclock with brothers and sisters

Tags: combine, genealogytree

I'm trying to combine two family trees. I want to have F1 - F5 on the left hand side with parents Q1 and Q2 and A1 - A3 on the right hand side with parents P1 and P2. F3 and A1 are married with Anne as their child.

How to make a ordered setup, where the F-Family and the A-Family are together respectively?

I've tried this code, but I'm not satisfied.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a0paper,landscape]{a0poster}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Pænere danske bogstaver
\usepackage{pslatex} % Giver pænere font
\usepackage[danish]{babel}

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
             \genealogytree[
    timeflow=up,
     processing=database,
     database format=medium no marriage,
     node size=3cm,   % width of nodes
     level size=3cm,              % height of nodes
     level distance=3cm,          % generation distance
     list separators hang,
   name font=\huge\bfseries,
     place text={\newline}{},
    date format=d-m-yyyy,
                             % redefine default setting for female,male,neuter:
    tcbset={
      female/.style={colback=red!20,arc=1mm},
       male/.style={colback=blue!20,sharp corners},
     },
    % node settings
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=left,fontlower=\Huge,fontupper=\Huge,before upper=\parskip10pt,
    \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
    },
    % edge settings
     edges={foreground={black,line width=1mm},    
           background={white,line width=2mm}},
   %Marriage-notes
            label database options={place text={(}{)}},
 label options={fill=green!20,node font=\large,inner      sep=0.5mm,draw=green!30!black,sloped,anchor=south,auto=true},
         id suffix=@a,]
   % %%%%% the graph %%%%%%
     {
     sandclock[id=MorOgFar,pivot shift=-30cm,family database={marriage={1936-04-    30}{}}]{
child[phantom*,id=migkirsten,family database={marriage={1961-08-22}     {Langelund}}]{
      g[id=mig,distance=30cm]{
      male,
      name={A1},
      }
   p[id=kirsten]{
      female,
      name={F3{}},
      }
       c[id=anne]{
          female,
          name={Anne {Sjælland}},
          }
          }
          c[]{female,name={A2}}
c{female,name={A3}}
parent{
g[id=far]{male,name={P1}}
}
parent{
g[id=mor]{female,name={P2}}
}
                    }
                    }
\genealogytree[
    timeflow=up,
    processing=database,
    database format=medium no marriage,
    node size=3cm,   % width of nodes
    level size=3cm,              % height of nodes
    level distance=3cm,          % generation distance
    list separators hang,
  name font=\huge\bfseries,
     place text={\newline}{},
    date format=d-m-yyyy,
                             % redefine default setting for     female,male,neuter:
    tcbset={
      female/.style={colback=red!20,arc=1mm},
      male/.style={colback=blue!20,sharp corners},
    },
    % node settings
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=left,fontlower=\Huge,fontupper=\Huge,before upper=\parskip10pt,
    \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
    },
    % edge settings
    edges={foreground={black,line width=1mm},    
           background={white,line width=2mm}},
  %Marriage-notes
           label database options={place text={(}{)}},
 label options={fill=green!20,node font=\large,inner     sep=0.5mm,draw=green!30!black,sloped,anchor=south,auto=true},
         id suffix=@b,set position=kirsten@b at kirsten@a]
    %%%%%% the graph %%%%%%
    {
    sandclock[id=MorOgFar,family database={marriage={1929-10-03}{Vester Nebel}}]    {
    c{female,name={F1}}
c{female,name={F2}}
child[id=migkirsten,family database={marriage={1961-08-22}{Langelund}}]{
      p[id=mig,set position=mig@b at mig@a]{
      male,
      name={A1},
      }
   g[id=kirsten,distance=-30cm]{
      female,
      name={F3{}},
      }
      c[id=anne]{
          female,
          name={Anne {Sjælland}},
          }
          }
         c{female,name={F4}}
c{female,name={F5}}
parent{
g[id=far]{male,name={Q1}}
}
parent{
g[id=mor]{female,name={Q2}}
}
                    }
                    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've figured a solution out now, but with mariage dates and Places I oot some Work ahead to avoid overlapping.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a0paper,landscape]{a0poster}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Pænere danske bogstaver
\usepackage{pslatex} % Giver pænere font
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
  \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
            \genealogytree[
    timeflow=up,
    processing=database,
    database format=medium no marriage,
    node size=3cm,   % width of nodes
    level size=3cm,              % height of nodes
    level distance=3cm,          % generation distance
    list separators hang,
  name font=\huge\bfseries,
    place text={\newline}{},
    date format=d-m-yyyy,
                             % redefine default setting for     female,male,neuter:
    tcbset={
      female/.style={colback=red!20,arc=1mm},
      male/.style={colback=blue!20,sharp corners},
    },
    % node settings
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=left,fontlower=\Huge,fontupper=\Huge,before upper=\parskip10pt,
    \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
    },
    % edge settings
    edges={foreground={black,line width=1mm},    
           background={white,line width=2mm}},
  %Marriage-notes
           label database options={place text={(}{)}},
 label options={fill=green!20,node font=\large,inner     sep=0.5mm,draw=green!30!black,sloped,anchor=south,auto=true},
         id suffix=@b,
         ]
    %%%%%% the graph %%%%%%
    {
    sandclock[id=MorOgFar,family database={marriage={1929-10-03}{Vester Nebel}}]    {
    c{female,name={F1}}
c{female,name={F2}}
child[id=migkirsten]{
         g[id=kirsten]{
      female,
      name={F3{}},
      }
          }
          c[id=f4]{female,name={F4}}
c[id=ff5]{female,name={F5}}
parent{
g[id=far]{male,name={Q1}}
}
parent{
g[id=mor]{female,name={Q2}}
}
                    }
                    }
\genealogytree[
    timeflow=up,
    processing=database,
    database format=medium no marriage,
    node size=3cm,   % width of nodes
    level size=3cm,              % height of nodes
    level distance=3cm,          % generation distance
    list separators hang,
  name font=\huge\bfseries,
    place text={\newline}{},
    date format=d-m-yyyy,
                             % redefine default setting for     female,male,neuter:
    tcbset={
      female/.style={colback=red!20,arc=1mm},
      male/.style={colback=blue!20,sharp corners},
    },
    % node settings
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=left,fontlower=\Huge,fontupper=\Huge,before upper=\parskip10pt,
    \gtrDBsex,drop fuzzy shadow,
    },
     % edge settings
      edges={foreground={black,line width=1mm},    
           background={white,line width=2mm}},
  %Marriage-notes
           label database options={place text={(}{)}},
 label options={fill=green!20,node font=\large,inner     sep=0.5mm,draw=green!30!black,sloped,anchor=south,auto=true},
         id suffix=@a,set position=kirsten@a at kirsten@b
         ]
    %%%%%% the graph %%%%%%
    {
    sandclock[id=MorOgFar,family database={marriage={1936-04-30}{}}]{
    child[id=migkirsten,family database={marriage={1961-08-22}{Langelund}}]{
 p[id=kirsten,phantom*,]{
      female,
      name={F3{}},
    }
         g[id=mig,distance=10cm]{
      male,
      name={A1},
      }
      c[id=anne]{
          female,
          name={Anne {Sjælland}},
          }
          }
         c[]{female,name={A2}}
c{female,name={A3}}
parent{
g[id=far]{male,name={P1}}
}
parent{
g[id=mor]{female,name={P2}}
}
                    }
                    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```